# Outer nested loop not working when taking file input

Tags: python, csv

Here is the code

```
f = open("mmk.tsv")
g = f
for a in f:
    print("-")
    for b in g:
        print("+")
```

The output is only one "-" and several "+"s.

When I remove the inner loop the outer loop works as expected.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you're facing, so that the community can help you. In this case, are you trying to parse a tab-seperated file?

Answer (score 1):

You can only iterate over a file once. Doing it through different variables doesn't change that.

Read file file into a list, then you can have multiple iterations.

```
with open("mmk.tsv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for a in lines:
    print("-")
    for b in lines:
        print("+")
```

Comment: _You can only iterate over a file once. Doing it through different variables doesn't change that_ it's just confusing